# Convert two points to a rectangle (cv::Rect)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have two points (assumed to be from a rectangle and are its top-left corner & bottom-right corner).

```
Point pTopLeft;
Point pBottomRight;
```

I want to formulate a `cv::Rect` using these points. So, I tried

```
cv::Rect rRect;
rRect.tl() = pTopLeft;
rRect.br() = pBottomRight;
```

There is no error. But the `Rect` seems to be containing nothing. i.e., both the points are indicating zero. So, How do I formulate a new `Rect` object with arbitrary two points?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since `Rect::tl()` and `Rect::br()` just return copies, not references, try a constructor:

```
cv::Rect rRect(pTopLeft, pBottomRight);
```

Comment: Assigning a value to a return function is not at all good. But my curiosity to formulate a Rect object using two points, lead me to ignore that point of thinking.

Comment: Be aware that right bottom point is exclusive. If you want the point to be included, try `cv::Rect rRect(pTopLeft, pBottomRight+cv::Point(1,1));`

Answer (score 7):

You have to calculate basic information from your two points: width and height. Then, create a new object using the following constructor :

---

```
(Object) rect(x, y, width, height)
```

---

```
pTopLeft.x = x

pTopLeft.y = y

pBottomRight.x - pTopLeft.x = width

pTopLeft.y - pBottomRight.y = height
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make it this way also,

```
Point pTopLeft;
Point pBottomRight;
cv::Rect rRect(pTopLeft.x,pTopLeft.y,pBottomRight.x-pTopLeft.x,pBottomRight.y-pTopLeft.y);
```