# How to resize image size (use opencv resize function)

Tags: opencv

[image]

This is original image.

For example, original image size is 1280x720.
Red rectangle size is 30x5.
If you know the rectangle vertex coordinates.

I want resize to rectangle area by 5x1 using opencv resize function.
So, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you already know the coordinates of red rectangle. So, create a (region of interest) ROI using **[rect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710264/convert-two-points-to-a-rectangle-cvrect)**. And, then resize its size using the `resize()` of openCV.

```
Mat original_image;
----
----
----
Rect region_of_interest(x, y, w, h);
Mat image_roi = image(region_of_interest);

Size size(5,1);   //the dst image size,e.g.5 x 1
Mat dst;          //dstimage
resize(image_roi ,dst,size);  //resize image
```

Answer (score 1):

Using opencv under python, this crops the image to the red rectangle and resizes 5x, saving the result as `closeup.jpg`:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('penguins.jpg', -1)
img2 = cv2.resize(img[65:65+92, 167:167+238], dsize=(0,0), fx=5, fy=5)
cv2.imwrite('closeup.jpg', img2)
```

If you are using a binding other than python, the function calls will need to be adjusted appropriately.  See the [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) for details.

The resulting image, closeup.jpg, looks like:
[image]

Note that the size of the original image, as downloaded from the question here, is 1024x768.  In this image, the upper-left corner of the red rectangle is located at 65,167 and has size 92x238.  The image closeup.jpg has size 460x1190.