# How to resize a depth map from size [400,400] into size [60,60]?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, kinect, opencv

I have a depth map image which was obtained using a kinect camera.
In that image I have selected a region of size [400,400] and stored it as another image.
Now, I would like to know how to resize this image into a size of [x,y] in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize image size (use opencv resize function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469837/how-to-resize-image-size-use-opencv-resize-function)

Comment: Are you asking for a set of methods for resizing (downsampling in this case)? Because there's a whole theory for it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling In general, you have to select a proper antialiasing filter, crop the corresponding image spectrum and reconstruct it into a smaller image.

Comment: @JeffUK I know that openCV resize function can be used for resizing an RGB or grayscale image, but I am not sure how to correctly resize a depth image using this function, since here each pixel is a z-coordinate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as a normal image

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread(path_to_your_image) # Insert your image address here
resized = cv2.resize(image, (x, y),  interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST) 

plt.imshow(resized)
plt.show()
```

Comment: an rgb image has 3 channels red, green and blue pixel values, whereas a depth image has only 1 channel, i.e z-coordinates, will this method still work correctly ?

Comment: @Win , yes all images are just numpy arrays from the prespective of python. Doesn't matter. Removing BGR2RGB line for removing ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend to reduce resolution of depth map the same way like it is done for images. Imagine a scene with a small object 5 m before the wall:

- Using bicubic/bilinear algorithms you will get depth of something between the object and the wall. In reality there is just a free space in between.
- Using nearest-neighbor interpolation is better but you are ignoring a lot of information and in some cases it may happed that the object just disappears.

The best approach is to use the Mode function. Divide the original depth map into windows. Each window will represent one pixel in the downsized map. For each of them calculate the most frequent depth value. You can use Python's `statistics.mode()` function.